# React Native OneSignal accessing push notification that initiated app start

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, onesignal

I'm using OneSignal in my React Native iOS app and I need to access whether app was started from push notification, and if yes, I need the push payload.

I haven't seen anything in OneSignal docs. Here is my code (called immediately at app constructor):

```
OneSignal.init('UID_REDACTED');
OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', onIds);
OneSignal.addEventListener('received', didReceiveNotification);
OneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(2) //0: none, 1: alert, 2: notif
OneSignal.configure();  // triggers the ids event
```

`onIds` function is triggered just fine, `didReceiveNotification` also works perfectly **if the app is already running**. If the app is started from tapping a push notification, this is not called. I need to handle that case as I need to deep link the push payload to actions.

How can I handle push notifications that caused app start in React Native with OneSignal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your question. It sounds like you're looking for `opened`...

```
onOpened(openResult) {
    console.log('Message: ', openResult.notification.payload.body);
    console.log('Data: ', openResult.notification.payload.additionalData);
    console.log('isActive: ', openResult.notification.isAppInFocus);
    console.log('openResult: ', openResult);
}
```

Link: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk#section-handling-notifications